webview2 wait to page to load (navigating several pages)
I'm creating a simple software that will download all images from a website, but I'm stuck in the "recursive" part of this software.
I'm using webview2 and it will do the following:

Navigate to the initial page;
Get all links from that page;
Navigate to each link from that page and download the image;
Go to the next page until finish (this part I guess I will do it "manually" via textbox since I don't know how many pages there are);

So, what I achieved right now is:
Function to navigate:
Private Sub WebsiteNavigate(ByVal dest As String)
    If webView IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dest) Then

        If Not dest = "about:blank" AndAlso
               Not dest.StartsWith("edge://") AndAlso
               Not dest.StartsWith("file://") AndAlso
               Not dest.StartsWith("http://") AndAlso
               Not dest.StartsWith("https://") AndAlso
               Not System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(dest, "^([A-Z]|[a-z]):") Then

            dest = "https://" & dest
        End If

        webView.Source = New Uri(dest, UriKind.Absolute)

    End If
End Sub

It should wait for page to load and list all the links:
Private Sub webView_NavigationCompleted(sender As Object, e As CoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs) Handles webView.NavigationCompleted
    If controlador = 0 Then
        ListFiles()
        btnstart.Enabled = True
    ElseIf controlador = 1 Then

    End If  
End Sub

That use the following function:
Async Sub ListFiles()

    Dim sHtml = Await webView.CoreWebView2.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.documentElement.outerHTML")
    Dim sHtmlDecoded = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Unescape(sHtml)

    Dim strRegex As String = "<?href\s*=\s*[""'].+?[""'][^>]*?"
    Dim link As String

    Dim myRegex As New Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.None)
    For Each myMatch As Match In myRegex.Matches(sHtmlDecoded)
        If myMatch.Success Then
            link = myMatch.ToString
            If link.Contains("product/") Then
                If Not link.Contains("pinterest") Then
                    link = link.Replace("""", "")
                    link = link.Replace("href=", "")
                    lblinks.Items.Add(link)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Dim items(lblinks.Items.Count - 1) As Object
    lblinks.Items.CopyTo(items, 0)
    lblinks.Items.Clear()
    lblinks.Items.AddRange(items.AsEnumerable().Distinct().ToArray())
End Sub

Then, I created the function to View each link and download the image:
Async Sub ViewAndDownload()
    Dim items = lblinks.Items.Count.ToString
    controlador = 1
    For x As Integer = 0 To lblinks.Items.Count - 1
        WebsiteNavigate(lblinks.Items(x))
        'Code to download image
    Next
End Sub

The problem here is that webview2 itself only "loads" the last item in listbox and doesn't wait for each one to be properly loaded.
What would be the best way to achieve a recursive method with webview2 so I can automate this task?
Thanks!

Why did you post code for ViewAndDownload without posting the code that call it? Also, please add the URL for the website you're working with to your post. One issue one may encounter with web scraping is that even if your code works today, it may no longer work tomorrow.

This is not the most efficient way to to this. Use WebClient with HtmlAgilityPack. The WebClient will download your HTML content and images, while the HtmlAgilityPack will allow you to select all links and images in the HTML. The only good reason to use WebView2 is if you need to dummy being a real browser (click on links, logging in etc. - i.e. more complex scraping that needs to mimic a real user).
Please be mindful that if you're trying to scrape a more sophisticated site then you're going to run into all sorts of problems, because content is typically loaded in as you scroll the page using AJAX, so you'd have to mimic all that scrolling to grab the contents - and you would then have no choice other than to use a WebView2. You are already well on the way with your code - you just need to track the events logically to know a page is fully loaded before moving onto the next task.
' This function gets the HTML from a URL
Function DownloadHTML(url As String) as String
  Using client As New WebClient()
    Try
      Return client.DownloadString(url)
    Catch ex As Exception
      Return ""
    End Try
  End Using
End Sub

' This function will return a list of hyperlinked URLs from HTML
' Use this as part of your nested crawl
Function GetAllLinksFromHTML(HTML as string) As List(of String)
  Dim Result As New List(Of String)
  Dim Doc As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()
  Doc.LoadHtml(HTML)
  Dim linkNodes As HtmlNodeCollection = 
  Doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]")
    If linkNodes IsNot Nothing Then
      For Each linkNode As HtmlNode In linkNodes
        Dim linkUrl As String = linkNode.GetAttributeValue("href", "")
        Result.Add(linkUrl)
      Next
    End If
  Return Result
End Function

' This function will return a list of all img src values from HTML
Function GetAllImageURLsFromHTML(HTML as string) As List(of String)
  Dim Result As New List(Of String)
  Dim Doc As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()
  Doc.LoadHtml(HTML)
  Dim imgNodes As HtmlNodeCollection = 
  Doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img[@src]")
    If imgNodes IsNot Nothing Then
      For Each imgNode As HtmlNode In imgNodes
        Dim imgSrc As String = imgNodes.GetAttributeValue("src", "")
        Result.Add(imgSrc)
      Next
    End If
End Sub

' This function downloads a file and stores it to disk
' Strongly recommend you check the extension for images here!!
Function DownloadFile(url As String, FilePath As String) as String
  Using client As New WebClient()
    Try
      client.DownloadFile(url,FilePath)
      Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
      Return False
    End Try
  End Using
End Sub

Sub Test()
   Dim HTML As String = DownloadHTML("https://www.your-test-url.com")
   Dim StoreToPath As String = "c:\temp\scraped_images"
   Dim I As Integer = 0
   For Each URL In GetAllImageURLsFromHTML(HTML)
      I+=1   
      ' Being lazy here and assuming all files are jpg - you need to write your own code to parse the filename and extension out of the url.
      DownloadFile(URL,StoreToPath & "\" & I & ".jpg")
   Next
End Sub


Thanks for your reply, but I think my main issued isn't covered in your reply. As an example, the site has 10 pages. Each page has 10 links. Inside those 10 links is one image. So I can get the code to navigate each page and retrieve all links (100 links in total). My issue then is making the browser to navigate each link, wait until page is loaded and download the image and then go to the next link. With my code actually the browser only loads the last page I retrieved. It seems it runs and doesn't wait to actually do the job.

WebView is the predecessor to WebView2 and is a different product, just as WebBrowser is different.

@user246821 - Yes, I know that - I've amended my answer. It boils down to the same thing - unless you need to interact with a website like a human would, the WebView2 is not the best way to do this.

@Tiago - If you have the list of image URLs (which you didn't need the WebView2 to get  - as per my answer) you don't need to use WebView2 to download the images either - just use the DownloadFile function I gave you. There is no need to use WebView2 to get data from the www - use WebClient instead unless you absolutely need to access the website as if a human is browsing it (all javascript / ajax to run and rendering to happen)
